# ssh config options are not applied recursively

Tags: ssh

I have something like this in my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host     foo
Hostname foo001.a.b.c.d

Host     bar
Hostname foo011.a.b.c.d

Host            *.a.b.c.d
ProxyCommand    ssh -A -l sds XXX.YYY.ZZZ.TTT nc %h %p

Host            *
ForwardAgent    yes
```

when I do `ssh -vvv foo` I see this:

```
$ ssh -vvv foo
debug1: /.../.ssh/config line 36: Applying options for foo
debug1: /.../.ssh/config line 50: Applying options for *
```

**Why is the option with `ProxyCommand` not applied?**
The `Host` there matches the `Hostname` in `foo`.

Is there a way to do what I want to, i.e., map short name to FQDNs and then handle them in separately?

Comment: as not that familiar with how to use the proxycommand line but you should show the ssh line you are using at the command line.

Comment: maybe if you want one to call another you have to do `Host foo <LF>Hostname *.a.b.c.d`  So maybe that will then call `Host *.a.b.c.d`

Comment: ssh command line is in the text of the question

Comment: If you say so. Though I don't see it. You could quote it in comment so I know what you're talking about.

Comment: the command is `ssh -vvv foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `Host` option, as described in manual page:

> The host is usually the hostname argument given on the command line (see the CanonicalizeHostname option for exceptions.)

The config is not re-parsed by default. If you want to match against modified hostname, you should give a try to `Match` keyword, which gives you more flexibility. You might achieve what you want by combining this with `CanonicalizeHostname`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that reapplying the rules after any hostname change was added unintentionally to OpenSSH and then later reverted (see [bug #2267](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2267)); the current version only does that when hostname canonicalization is enabled. (Somewhat annoyingly the more permissive version got included at least into Ubuntu 14/15 so updating those to 16 might break your SSh config.)

A somewhat dirty workaround is to set

```
Host *
  CanonicalizeHostname yes
  CanonicalizeMaxDots 0
```

which won't actually do any canonicalization but will enable re-reading the config file and so will make your example work.